# json-schema describe object key's values (when keys are dynamic)

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have an object that has dynamic key names and I want to describe the value schema  that the keys can have, ie:

```
{
   "properties": {
      "usersById": {
         "additionalProperties": {
            "properties": {
               "email": {
                  "type": "boolean"
               },
               "phone": {
                  "type": "boolean"
               },
               "address": {
                  "type": "boolean"
               }
            },
            "type": "object"
         },
         "type": "object"
      }
   },

   ...
}
```

This doesn't appear to be doing anything in my validation step (using AJV JS pkg). I want to restrict to only this model schema:

```
{
  usersById: {
    '1234abcd': {
      email: true,
      phone: false,
      address: false,
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `patternProperties` which is like `properties` but you use a regex.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.5

An example...

Schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^S_": { "type": "string" },
    "^I_": { "type": "integer" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Valid instance:

```
{ "I_0": 42 }
```

Invalid instance:

```
{ "S_0": 42 }
```

Example lifted from https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties

As a note, it's good to remember that these regexes are not implicitly anchored, so you'll need to anchor them should you require anchored regexes.

Comment: If you want to do some playground work, check out https://jsonschema.dev